# Can a Housesitter allow a bailiff entry to a property?

Tags: united-kingdom, ownership, breach-of-contract, debt

This question fairly closely relates to the below linked question, but does differ in it’s question.

[Legal standing as a house-sitter during a bailiff visit](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/76545/legal-standing-as-a-house-sitter-during-a-bailiff-visit)

Suppose a high court writ has been received to collect on a debt. The person owed the debt knows for a fact that the occupants are away for a significant period of time, and knows that the Housesitter would be amenable to their cause. Could the Housesitter allow entry to bailiffs to assess goods in the house? Or would they not be allowed to give entry legally speaking?

This supposed situation is happening in Wales

Comment: Did the house-sitter sign a contract or otherwise agree to restrictions on who should enter? If the house-sitter genuinely believed they had a legal duty to let someone in, and had been not told otherwise by the homeowner, it would be hard to argue that the housesitter did anything wrong. In contrast, if the owner told the housesitter "Don't let anyone in even if they say they have a warrant or are legally allowed to enter" then I'd advise the housesitter to get legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Anyone with ostensible authority over the property can allow access. That’s how most vampires get in.